# How many lines does a text have? Different results with different methods

Tags: python, algorithm, shell, text, operating-system

It is a very simple question which seem to have no solid and right answer.

The problem appears to be lack of detailed clarity what the word 'line' in a context of a text kept in memory or on a storage device of a computer system is.

Although The POSIX standard does define what a 'Line' is, it mentions also along with its definition the concepts of an 'Incomplete Line' and 'Blank Line' opening the door to different interpretations (Is an incomplete line always a line? Is a blank line always a line?)

To demonstrate what I am speaking about let's take a look how to count lines of a text using Python programming language and sh shell commands. The code below uses eight different methods and applies them to six different texts:

```
'''How many lines has a text (with leading and/or trailing newlines)?'''
CR = '\r' # Carriage Return
LF = '\n' # Line Feed
assert CR == '\r' == '\015' == '\x0D' == chr(13)
assert LF == '\n' == '\012' == '\x0A' == chr(10)
import linecache
import re
from subprocess import run
Lines = [ r"       line N       "
        , r"\n     line N       "
        , r"       line N     \n"
        , r"\n     line N     \n"
        , r"\n\n   line N   \n\n"
        , r"\n line N\nline M \n" ]
Methods = [ r'len(f.readlines()) '
           ,r's.splitlines()     '
           ,r'linecache.get(f,N))' 
           ,r'subprocess: grep ^ ' 
           ,r's.split("\n")      ' 
           ,r're.split("\n",s)   ' 
           ,r's.count("\n")      ' 
           ,r'subprocess: wc -l  ' 
          ]
from pprint import pprint
pprint(Methods)
text_as_file   = 'how_many_lines.txt'
for line in Lines:
    noLines = []
    text_as_string = eval(f'str("{line}")') if line else ''
    #print('                >>>>>', text_as_string, '<<<<<')
    with open(text_as_file, 'w') as f: 
        f.write(text_as_string) 
    # ==================================================================
    with open(text_as_file) as f: 
        lines_of_text_from_file_readlines = f.readlines()
    noLines.append(len(lines_of_text_from_file_readlines))
    # ^-- 0 ------------------------------------------------------------
    lines_of_text_from_string_splitlines = text_as_string.splitlines()
    noLines.append(len(lines_of_text_from_string_splitlines))
    # ^-- 1 ------------------------------------------------------------
    no_of_lines_by_linecache = 0 
    linecache.checkcache(text_as_file)    
    for lineno in range(1,6):
        theline = linecache.getline(text_as_file, lineno)
        if theline != '': # trailing CR or '' if Error (no such line)
            no_of_lines_by_linecache += 1
    noLines.append(no_of_lines_by_linecache)
    # ^-- 3 ------------------------------------------------------------
    noLines.append(int(run('grep -c ^ "how_many_lines.txt"',
               shell=True,capture_output=True).stdout.decode()[:-1],
                  )) # counts '\n'
    # ^-- 6 ------------------------------------------------------------
    lines_of_text_from_string_split_by_newline = text_as_string.split('\n')
    noLines.append(len(lines_of_text_from_string_split_by_newline))
    # ^-- 2 ------------------------------------------------------------
    lines_of_text_from_re_split = re.split('\n', text_as_string)
    noLines.append(len(lines_of_text_from_re_split))
    # ^-- 4 ------------------------------------------------------------
    no_of_lines_by_count_newlines = text_as_string.count('\n')
    noLines.append(no_of_lines_by_count_newlines)
    # ^-- 5 ------------------------------------------------------------
    noLines.append(int(run('wc -l < "how_many_lines.txt"',
               shell=True,capture_output=True).stdout.decode()[:-1],
                  )) # counts '\n'
    # ^-- 7 ------------------------------------------------------------
    print(f' r"{line}"', noLines)
```

Below a list with the short description of the eight different methods :

```
['len(f.readlines()) ',
 's.splitlines()     ',
 'linecache.get(f,N))',
 'subprocess: grep ^ ',
 's.split("\\n")      ',
 're.split("\\n",s)   ',
 's.count("\\n")      ',
 'subprocess: wc -l  ']
```

and an array with results from which can be seen that the methods can be put in three groups depending on which result they give:

```
 r"       line N       " [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
 r"\n     line N       " [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
 r"       line N     \n" [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
 r"\n     line N     \n" [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]
 r"\n\n   line N   \n\n" [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4]
 r"\n line N\nline M \n" [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Let's take a look how different text editors are numbering lines of the last of the six texts used in the programming example above:

[image: How many lines?]

Another aspect of the definition of a line is that Microsoft Windows uses two and the Unix/Linux world one character to terminate a text line. So there is along with the problem of last not by line break terminated text line also no consensus about the codes of boundaries making a part of a text a line.

After showing all the above evidence now in this context the actual question:

#### **Am I right stating that there is no clear solid and unambiguous definition in the world of programming languages and operating systems of what a text line actually is and how to count lines in a document/text?**

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446237/4667